# Button placement on modals – should it be consistent at ALL times?

Tags: buttons, modal-windows, tablet

I'm currently designing an app for iPads.

I illustrated the situation below:[image: Image descirbing guy's problem]

The screen on the left is current version which seems to work really well when the user doesn't have to use the keyboard or when there's only one or two textfields (then, modal window is short enough for the keyboard to fit with the "Create" button).

Currently, when the keyboard is overlapping the window (middle picture) I am moving the "create" button to the top-right corner, so that the primary button is not obstructed.

- Should I change the middle-picture version to the one on the right in
  order to be consistent?
- Is there any other solution for my problem?

Cheers and sorry for bad english ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could switch directly from pressing the field to an active state where the only 3 actions are: keyboard, enter, cancel.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fER91b.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Keep placement consistent:

**#4: Consistency and standards**

Users should not have to wonder whether different words, situations, or actions mean the same thing. Follow platform conventions.

From https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/